# Save React component

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

I have a "container" react component which contains other react components. I want to save the "container" component (with its children) in mongodb a then get it from there. **What is the best practice to do it?** (user will add and edit those components in the container)

Comment: Weird request not sure why you can't just save positions of elements etc. However, it is possible(-ish) to render components to json and then convert them back. How successful this is, I am not sure. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-renderer

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: you need to save the domain state or the view state?

Comment: @Purgatory Well, saving positions is not enough for me - Elements in the container could contain text, images, or another react element... So I need something, what I can save to the database, that will tell me - "Container contains two components, The first is type of "TestComponent", size 10x10, color: 'blue', position 0, 0, children: <p>...</p> the second one is type of Image, size 400x400."

Comment: @Hitmands View state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at: [`react-pstate`](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/03/05/persistent-state-reactjs/) and then find out a way to use your web service as storage...

https://github.com/mgechev/react-pstate it uses localStorage currently...

---

A further approach could be using some render...

look at this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-test-renderer

```
const ReactTestRenderer = require('react-test-renderer');

const renderer = ReactTestRenderer.create(
  <Link page="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</Link>
);

console.log(renderer.toJSON());
// { type: 'a',
//   props: { href: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
//   children: [ 'Facebook' ] }
```

Comment: I gave it a quick view. And it contains some useful code. For now it looks like its "only" save a state, but I need to save type of containers children as well (or did I miss something?)

Comment: Did you check how react-renderer creates a snapshot??

Comment: and for state I should make a new function? I guess the container should contains state of its children, so I write function 'getState' (or something like that) there?

Comment: Maybe! honestly, yours is a big challenge... It will require some hours to figure out...

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. From what you describe, I would imagine making a JSON which 'describes' the component state. This structure can be up to you, but I have done things similar to:

```
{
  title: 'Foo',
  children: [{
    title: 'c1',
    component: 'Header',
    description: 'c1 description'
  }, { 
    title: 'c2',
    component: 'Article',
    description: 'c2 description'
  }]
}
```

And just created custom render methods to dynamically populate children.

EDIT: I added `component` to the children. This allows you to identify which component to use. You will need to create something that converts this string into a reference to the actual component before rendering. Example below:

```js
const fromMongo = {
  title: 'Foo',
  children: [{
    title: 'c1',
    component: 'Header',
    description: 'c1 description'
  }, { 
    title: 'c2',
    component: 'Article',
    description: 'c2 description'
  }]
}

const Header = p => (
  <header>{p.title}</header>
)
const Article = p => (
  <article>{p.title}</article>
)

const components = {
  Header,
  Article,
}

class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    fromMongo.children.map(d => (
      d.component = components[d.component]
    ))
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {fromMongo.children.map(d => (
          <d.component title={d.title} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```css
header {
 background-color: blue;
}

article {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: So the container should contains property (for example containersElements), which should mirroring the real hierarchy of my components?

Comment: this won't reflect dom attributes (classes, stylesheets, ecc...)